# AWS RDS engine mode currently unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to create an RDS Cluster Aurora-MySQL with one instance in it.

I get this error: "**InvalidParameterValue: The engine mode provisioned you requested is currently unavailable**"

I tried using "serverless" and get the same error.

Region: Ireland (eu-west-1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you create it via the AWS Management Console or using the API or CLI?

Comment: @Pampy I'm using Terraform

Comment: Then maybe some parameter is wrong. Can you maybe post the configuration you're using to set it up?

Comment: Yep indeed, please provide the terraform code snippet you are trying to execute

Comment: source code should be provided if you expect any help from Stackoverflow

Comment: I didn't think its a Terraform issue but now it was solved. Guess I didn't put the right attributes at the right place. For some reason the Terraform did not create my Aurora-Mysql and always created an Aurora only. Now I put the engine+engine version in both the cluster and the instance configuration and it works

Comment: Nope, not a Terraform issue, but wrong parameters :D
You can resolve with your own answer if it's resolved now.

Comment: Source code especially for "Infrastructure as code" is always needed. Not to mention this configuration neglects to specify the provider version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`engine` and `engine_version` are mandatory parameters for Create API calls, be it instance or cluster. When you provision via AWS Console, these details are taken care of automatically by the console, but if you're using the SDK or CLI, you'd need to pass in all the parameters explicitly. The MAN pages and/or AWS Docs would come of help in such cases.

P.S. I did expect a different error message though for this case.

Answer (score 13):

This error is also encountered when incorrectly trying to configure a serverless v2 configuration.

It's a bit unintuitive, but `engine_mode = "serverless"` works for v1 and `engine_mode = "provisioned"` is required for v2.

To ensure that you have a serverless v2 cluster you need:

```
engine_mode = "provisioned"
instance_class = "db.serverless"
engine_version = "15.2"
```

Note, the engine version will change over time. You can see which ones are available by using this CLI command:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine aurora-postgresql --db-instance-class db.serverless \
  --region us-east-1 --query 'OrderableDBInstanceOptions[].[EngineVersion]' --output text
```

Answer (score 4):

When I put `engine = aurora-mysql` only in the cluster or only in the instance configuration it didn't work. I needed to put it in both.

This is the working code for now

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds-cluster" {
    cluster_identifier = "${var.env}-cluster"
    engine = "aurora-mysql"
    engine_version = "5.7.12"
    database_name = "${var.env}rds"
    master_username = "${var.env}"
    master_password = "**********"
    backup_retention_period = 5
    preferred_backup_window = "04:00-22:00"
    skip_final_snapshot = true
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "rds-instance" {
    count = 1
    identifier = "${var.env}-db-${count.index}"
    cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.rds-cluster.id}"
    instance_class = "db.r4.large"
    engine_version = "5.7.12"
    engine = "aurora-mysql"
}
```